# How to send FCM notification to iOS in C#

Tags: c#, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send push notification to android and iOS using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging). I followed this link:
[Firebase Cloud Messaging and C# server side code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257160/firebase-cloud-messaging-and-c-sharp-server-side-code/39389204#39389204)
It's working well for my Android app and I'm getting notification but in iOS app I'm getting this:

```
{\"multicast_id\":7009xxxxxxxxxxxx676,
 \"success\":0,
 \"failure\":1,
 \"canonical_ids\":0,
 \"results\":[{\"error\":\"InvalidRegistration\"}]}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve this, actually problem is spelling mistake in Xcode appside i.e 
- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
so, it's working for both language's app.